# Build Error with AWS SDK iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I downloaded the `SDK` from the `Cognito` service, and installed it under this instruction (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html).

I installed the pod, and added the frameworks to my project. When I tried to run my project, I got an error `including ld: 6705 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64`.

For example:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSEC2ResponseSerializer in:
    /Users/haichen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSTest-ceywyjkmugdxssfeodliqhmuehlz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-AWSEC2.a(AWSEC2Service.o)
    /Users/haichen/Documents/AWSTest/aws-ios-sdk-2.1.1/frameworks/AWSEC2.framework/AWSEC2(AWSEC2Service.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AWSEC2ResponseSerializer in:
    /Users/haichen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSTest-ceywyjkmugdxssfeodliqhmuehlz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-AWSEC2.a(AWSEC2Service.o)
    /Users/haichen/Documents/AWSTest/aws-ios-sdk-2.1.1/frameworks/AWSEC2.framework/AWSEC2(AWSEC2Service.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSEC2RequestRetryHandler in:
    /Users/haichen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSTest-ceywyjkmugdxssfeodliqhmuehlz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-AWSEC2.a(AWSEC2Service.o)
    /Users/haichen/Documents/AWSTest/aws-ios-sdk-2.1.1/frameworks/AWSEC2.framework/AWSEC2(AWSEC2Service.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AWSEC2RequestRetryHandler in:
    /Users/haichen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSTest-ceywyjkmugdxssfeodliqhmuehlz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-AWSEC2.a(AWSEC2Service.o)
    /Users/haichen/Documents/AWSTest/aws-ios-sdk-2.1.1/frameworks/AWSEC2.framework/AWSEC2(AWSEC2Service.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSEC2 in:
    /Users/haichen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSTest-ceywyjkmugdxssfeodliqhmuehlz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-AWSEC2.a(AWSEC2Service.o)
    /Users/haichen/Documents/AWSTest/aws-ios-sdk-2.1.1/frameworks/AWSEC2.framework/AWSEC2(AWSEC2Service.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AWSEC2 in:
    /Users/haichen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSTest-ceywyjkmugdxssfeodliqhmuehlz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-AWSEC2.a(AWSEC2Service.o)
    /Users/haichen/Documents/AWSTest/aws-ios-sdk-2.1.1/frameworks/AWSEC2.framework/AWSEC2(AWSEC2Service.o)
ld: 6705 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Could anyone help me find out the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using both the frameworks and Cocoapods. You cannot import the SDK using both of the methods at the same time. You need to choose one of them and remove the other one.

Answer (score 5):

Close your project.
Clear all derived data.
Quit Xcode and reopen it
Make sure you open .xcworkspace file instead of .xcodeproj of your project.

To clear Derived Data: 
XCode -> Window -> Projects 
Select your project
press delete button in front of derived data

Let me know if it help

Comment: I am sure I open the .xcworkspace file. I cleaned the project and built it again, but I have the same issue. How can I clear all derive data, what does derive data mean?

Comment: Awasom...!  It save my day...@@

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the derived data, clean the proj and re-compile.